# Spark SQL JOIN gives different execution times when using df.repartition versus reading in and using a partitioned Parquet

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am doing a Broadcast Hash join of two DataFrames on a common id.

I noticed that when I try `DataFrame.repartition("id")` and pass the DataFrames into the `JOIN` query, the execution time is a lot slower than if I write the DataFrames to Parquet files with `DataFrame.write.partitionBy("id")`, then read in the Parquet as a DataFrame before passing it into the query.

Why is there a difference between repartitioning the DataFrame versus reading in a DataFrame from a partitioned Parquet?

Both the first and second case have an equal number of partitions when I call `df.rdd.getNumPartitions()`, and both DataFrames are sorted and partitioned according to the `id` column.

For `DataFrame.repartition("id")` the query time is three minutes, taking three jobs with 7 stages altogether.

For partitioning into Parquet, the query time is one minute, with one job and 1 stage.

1 dataset is 41 mil rows while the other is 2 mil rows.

Comment: how much slower ? can you share some metrics on execution time and the volume of data you have ?

Comment: did you try to compare the DAGs to see what are the different steps ?

Comment: Yes. The faster query does a single parquet scan, whole stage code gen, project and sort, while the slower one has multiple exchanges and sorts. My hypothesis is that the repartitioning doesn't arrange the data in a way that streamlines downstream queries (hence the need to shuffle extensively), while the parquet partitionBy keeps the data in an order that helps make the join query more efficient

Comment: Are you comparing time of `write.partition + read from parquet + join` ? or just `read from parquet + join ` ?

Comment: @Sanket9394 actually just the join operation itself

Comment: Did you perform an `Action` after repartition  and then trigger Join ? can share your sample code .